# How to show the battery status in an app with an icon?

Tags: android, sdk, battery

I want to develop an Android battery app, which shows the battery status on an icon/picture,  like in the android app: Battery Doctor (Battery Saver)

And can somebody tell me, how I can calculate the time the battery will last?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

Comment: I can't see any way to get the battery time from that, but I would imagine you could use a few reference points and do some easy math to calculate how much battery is being used per minute, and multiply it by the battery charge level.

Comment: There is no easy answer for this, since different phones running different apps will show different performance levels. Also, the rate of discharge will change depending on how much charge is left in the device, in part due to charge level measuring inaccuracies. To be really accurate, you would need to monitor the charge levels on the device as it discharges several times, and learn the rate of discharge for that device and how it changes over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android battery documentatation is here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html

Coding examples are here:

https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

You can check if the battery is plugged in, for example, as follows:

```
IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ActionBatteryChanged);
Intent batteryStatus = Android.App.Application.Context.RegisterReceiver(null, ifilter);
int i = batteryStatus.GetIntExtra(BatteryManager.ExtraPlugged, -1);
string s = "AC";
    if (i == 0)
    {
        s = "Battery";
    }
```